# Substitute value with result of calling function on value in unix shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a text stream that looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------
s123456789_9780
  heartbeat:test       @ 1344280205000000: '0'
  heartbeat:test       @ 1344272490000000: '0'
```

Those long numbers are timestamps in microseconds.  I would like to run this output through some sort of pipe that will change those timestamps to a more human-understandable date.

I have a date command that can do that, given just the timestamp (with the following colon):

```
$ date --date=@$(echo 1344272490000000: | sed 's/.......$//') +%Y/%d/%m-%H:%M:%S
2012/06/08-10:01:30
```

I would like to end up with something like this:

```
----------------------------------------
s123456789_9780
  heartbeat:test       @ 2012/06/08-12:10:05: '0'
  heartbeat:test       @ 2012/06/08-10:01:30: '0'
```

I don't think `sed` will allow me to match the timestamp and replace it with the value of calling a shell function on it (although I'd love to be shown wrong).  Perhaps `awk` can do it?  I'm not very familiar with `awk`.

The other part that seems tricky to me is letting the lines that don't match through without modification.

I could of course write a Python program that would do this, but I'd rather keep this in shell if possible (this is generated inside a shell script, and I'd rather not have dependencies on outside files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash with a little sed, preserving the whitespace of the input:

```
while read -r; do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    parts=($REPLY)
    if [[ ${parts[0]} == "heartbeat:test" ]]; then
        dateStr=$(date --date=@${parts[2]%000000:} +%Y/%d/%m-%H:%M:%S)
        REPLY=$(echo "$REPLY" | sed "s#[0-9]\+000000:#$dateStr#")
    fi
    printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"
done
```

Comment: Whitespace preservation is awesome!  I changed the sed expression to use `#` instead of `/` so I don't have to do all that escaping, but otherwise this works wonderfully!  Just for my edification, the `parts=($REPLY)` line is just splitting `$REPLY` into an array using the IFS, right?

Comment: That's right. Good idea changing the delimiter for sed; I wish I'd remembered that was an option. I'll update the answer to use #.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/@ /!b;s//&\n/;h;s/.*\n//;s#\(.\{10\}\)[^:]*\(:.*\)#date --date=@\1 +%Y/%d/%m-%H:%M:%S"\2"#e;H;g;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Explanation:

- `/@ /!b` bail out and just print any lines that don't contain an `@` followed by a space
- `s//&\n/` insert a newline after the above pattern
- `h` copy the pattern space (PS) to the hold space (HS)
- `s/.*\n//` delete upto and including the `@` followed by a space
- `s#\(.\{10\}\)[^:]*\(:.*\)#date --date=@\1 +%Y/%d/%m-%H:%M:%S"\2"#e` from whats remaining in the PS, make a back reference of the first 10 characters and from the `:` to the end of the string. Have these passed in to the `date` command and evaluate the result into the PS
- `H` append the PS to the HS inserting a newline at the same time
- `g` copy the HS into the PS
- `s/\n.*\n//` remove the original section of the string

Comment: The e flag works with files, but not with functions. I am using GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Comment: @michelpm this probably only works with GNU sed within a linux/unix bash environment.

Comment: @potong as I said, I am using GNU sed version 4.2.1 and I tested on Ubuntu 13.04 with both bash and zsh. It DOES work with **executable files**, but not with **functions**. `square () { echo $(($1 * $1)) }`, `seq () { for (( i = 0 ; i < $1 ; i++ )); do echo $i; done }`, `seq 10 | sed 's/[0-9]*/square &/ge'` complains that function square doesn't exist. It does work if I turn the square function into `square.sh` and change sed to call the file instead. Any ideas?

Comment: @potong [a inlined version](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70606/30575) works though: `seq 10 | sed 's/[0-9]*/echo \$((& * &))/ge'`

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to see a `sed` solution, but it is a bit beyond my `sed`-fu. As `awk` supports `strftime` it is fairly straight forward here:

```
awk '
/^ *heartbeat/ { 
  gsub(".{7}$", "", $3)
  $3 = strftime("%Y/%d/%m-%T", $3)
  print " ", $1, $3
}

$0 !~ /heartbeat/' file
```

Output:

```
s123456789_9780
heartbeat:test 2012/06/08-21:10:05
heartbeat:test 2012/06/08-19:01:30
```

`$3` is the microsecond field. `gsub` converts the timestamp to seconds.

The `$0 !~` makes sure non-heartbeat lines are printed (`{ print }` implicitly is the default block).

Comment: I don't think `gsub` is working -- I run this, and I get dates of 42600513/23/11-15:33:20, which is a little bit off. :-)

Comment: That's odd, I've added what I get to the answer. Which version of `awk` are you using? I've tested this with `gawk`.

Comment: I'm using GNU awk 3.1.6.  If I remove the `strftime` line, then I'm getting the long timestamps.

Comment: Maybe try with the original format string you were using? `%Y/%d/%m-%H:%M:%S`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work -- if I change the regexp from `".{7}$"` to `"000000:"` it does work, though.

Comment: Interesting, I thought interval expressions were supported in most versions of `awk`. Anyway, you could use the same "trick" that you had in your original `sed` solution, the seven dots `.......`.

Comment: You should be able to make interval expressions work by adding the `-r` switch to `gawk`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
while read s1 at tm s2
do 
    tm=${tm%000000:}
    echo $s1 $at $(date --date @$tm +%Y/%d/%m-%H:%M:%S)
done < yourfile
```

Comment: This barfs on the lines without the timestamps -- I like the simplicity, though.

Answer (score 0):

This does it mostly within `bash` using your `date` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$
while read a ; do
case "$a" in
*" @ "[0-9]*) pre=${a% @ *}
              a=${a#$pre @ }
              post=${a##*:}
              a=${a%??????:$post}
              echo "$pre$(date --date=@$a +%Y/%d/%m-%H:%M:%S):$post"
              ;;
*)            echo "$a" ;;
esac
done <<.
----------------------------------------
s123456789_9780
  heartbeat:test       @ 1344280205000000: '0'
  heartbeat:test       @ 1344272490000000: '0'
.
```