# How to change date string in txt file?

Tags: bash, text, replace

I have a txt file with this type of date strings : `2011-05-21 19:30:00`
I would like to search all the txt file and replace this "Year-month-day" string to "day MonthInLetter year"

Search and replace.

Two more parameters.
I would like to delete the Hour just after the date.
And affect only the hour that have `meta_value>` string before it.

```
meta_value>2011-07-24 22:00:00
```

become

```
meta_value>24 July 2011
```

Can you help me?

Thanks!

edit:

The file is parsed like this:

```
 <item>
      <title><![CDATA[UN VIOLON SUR LE TOIT AH, SI J’ETAIS RICHE! ]]></title>
      <pubDate/>
      <dc:creator>admin</dc:creator>
      <description/>
      <content:encoded/>
      <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>evcal_start_date</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>2010-02-04 11:00:00</wp:meta_value>
      </wp:postmeta>
      <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>evcal_end_date</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>2010-07-31 20:00:00</wp:meta_value>
      </wp:postmeta>
      <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>evcal_location</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>8 rue du Fbg Montmartre, 75009 Paris</wp:meta_value>
      </wp:postmeta>
      <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>evcal_organizer</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>Le Palace</wp:meta_value>
      </wp:postmeta>
      <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>evcal_allday</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>no</wp:meta_value>
      </wp:postmeta>
      <wp:post_date/>
      <wp:post_date_gmt/>
      <wp:comment_status/>
      <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
      <wp:post_name>un-violon-sur-le-toit-ah-si-jretais-riche-</wp:post_name>
      <wp:status/>
      <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
      <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
      <wp:post_type>ajde_events</wp:post_type>
      <wp:post_password/>
      <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
      <category domain="category" nicename=""/>
    </item>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11891424/358679

Answer (score 1):

You could use a perl "one-liner" to do so:

```
perl -wi -pe 'BEGIN{@month=('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')};
s/meta_value>(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d) \d\d:\d\d:\d\d/"meta_value>$3 $month[0+$2] $1"/eg'
```

Adapt the month names as you like.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the month names, let a library handle that for you: `perl -MTime::Piece -i -pe 's/meta_value>\K(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%Y-%m-%d %T")->strftime("%d %B %Y")/eg'` This will also respect your locale

Answer (score 1):

> Using date, you can convert from the first date format to the second:
>
> `date --date='2011-07-24 22:00:00' '+%d %B %Y'`
>
> *It doesn't work in Mac OS X*

In Mac OS X, you need to use the *BSD form* of the `date` command:

```
$ date -j -f"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2011-07-24 22:00:00" +"%d %B %Y" 
24 July 2011
```

- The `-j` says _Don't set the date"
- The `-f` takes two arguments: The date format and the date. `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` is the format and `"2011-07-24 22:00:00"` is the date.
- The "+" is the format you want the output to be.

You can do a `man strftime` from the Terminal window to see the various date format characters.

---

## Addendum

> can i replace "2011-07-24 22:00:00" by a file containing many things but also dates in this format?
>   dansayag

You couldn't use `sed`, but you could read the file line-by-line and munge the lines if they contain a date. Untested:

```
while read line
    do
    if ! grep -q "<wp:meta_value>"
    then
        echo "$line" >> $new_file_name
    else
        date=${line#<wp:meta_value>}  #Removes prefix
        date=${date%</wp:meta_value>} #Removes suffix
        date=$(date -j -f"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "$date" +"%d %B %Y")
        echo "<wp:meta_value>$date</wp:meta_value>" >> $new_file_name
    fi
done < FileName
```

See `man bash` and look at the section about `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter%word}` for an explanation of the `${line#<wp:meta_value>}` syntax.

Comment: can i replace "2011-07-24 22:00:00" by a file containing many things but also dates in this format?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This allows you to convert any date from one format to another.

Comment: Sorry i missed a word. I mean don't want to convert only one date. I have thousands in a file.

Comment: Okay, you have a file with 1000s of dates in it. Are all of the dates just dates on a line, or are they embedded in text? Is there a difference between formats when you have `metadata>` and when you don't? Can you paste a sample of the file in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com)? That gives me something to work with.

Comment: this look like this  <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>evcal_start_date</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>2012-05-02 20:00:00</wp:meta_value>
      </wp:postmeta>

Comment: and it goes on with a lot a variables like this but also other var, text, and also date that appear in other situations.

Comment: <item>
<title><![CDATA[Hayati Kafé]]></title>
 <pubDate/>
<dc:creator>admin</dc:creator>
      <description/>
      <content:encoded/>
      <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>evcal_start_date</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>2013-06-06 20:30:00</wp:meta_value>
      </wp:postmeta>
      <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>evcal_end_date</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>2013-06-06 22:30:00</wp:meta_value>
      </wp:postmeta>
      <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>evcal_location</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>39 rue Broca, 75005 Paris</wp:meta_value>

Comment: @dansayag See my addendum above.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`date`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date), you can convert from the first date format to the second:

```
date --date='2011-07-24 22:00:00' '+%d %B %Y'
```

Result:

```
24 July 2011
```

Comment: 1. It doesn't work in Mac OS X; 2. I suppose the `%B`, instead of `%b`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
$ cat file
meta_value>2011-07-24 22:00:00
meta_value>2011-12-25 22:00:00

$ sed -re 's/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/\0 01Jan02Feb03Mar04Apr05May06Jun07Jul08Aug09Sep10Oct11Nov12DecEND/g' -e 's/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} .*\2(...).*END/\3 \4 \1/g' file

meta_value>24 Jul 2011
meta_value>25 Dec 2011
```

The idea is to add a string of month number to month name mappings and use that as a lookup.

Comment: <wp:meta_value>0 01January02February03March04April05May06June07July08August09September10October11November12DecemberEND</wp:meta_value>

Comment: by the way i have others strings like 2011-07-24 22:00:00 but i don't want to change them as they don't have meta_value> string before them.

Comment: My solution is not going to work if you want the full names of the months. It will only work if you want the first 3 characters of the month.

Comment: <item>
      <title><![CDATA[Hayati KafÃ©]]></title>
      <pubDate/>
      <dc:creator>admin</dc:creator>
      <description/>
      <content:encoded/>
      <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>evcal_start_date</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>0 01Jan02Feb03Mar04Apr05May06Jun07Jul08Aug09Sep10Oct11Nov12DecEND</wp:meta_value>
      </wp:postmeta>
      <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>evcal_end_date</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>0 01Jan02Feb03Mar04Apr05May06Jun07Jul08Aug09Sep10Oct11Nov12DecEND</wp:meta_value>

Comment: Even with only the Three Letters it replace everything date with 0 01Jan02Feb03Mar04Apr05May06Jun07Jul08Aug09Sep10Oct11Nov12DecEND

Comment: If I use my command (exactly as shown in my answer above) on your file, I get the correct output. Please check you have not changed my command when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

You should always consider `python`, `ruby` or `perl` for these kind of string processing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

s = 'meta_value>2011-07-24 22:00:00'
d = s[s.index('>') + 1:]
ds = time.strftime('%d %B %Y', time.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print "%s%s" % (s[:s.index('>') + 1], ds)
```

Moreover, the python code is clean and human readable.

Comment: what is the command to replace and read the strings in the file?